# LinkedIn get connections

Tags: java, linkedin-api

After I get the access token and secret, access my account I want to get my connections with their profiles,

```
Connections cc = client.getConnectionsForCurrentUser();

for(Person p :cc.getPersonList()) {
    System.out.println(p.getLastName());
    System.out.println("Industry      "+p.getIndustry());
    System.out.println("currentStatus "+p.getCurrentStatus());
    System.out.println("link          "+p.getPublicProfileUrl());
    System.out.println("position      "+p.getEducations());
    System.out.println();
}
```

but most of the fields I get are null.  I don't know where I went wrong, can anyone help?

Comment: have you get the solution for the same because i am facing problem in which i wont get any connections from  `client.getConnectionsForCurrentUser();` it returns null, please share some code with me for getting connections of current user.

Answer (score 0):

If a Connection hasn't provided the information you are requesting, the results for that field will indeed be null.  Are you able to retrieve any information about your connections, such as first-name, last-name?